# How to copy files when files are in different folder than the dockerfile?

Tags: windows, docker

I need to build a docker image and need to copy a file from the different folder which don't have docker file

Basically this is my dir structure

```
C:\AGENT\_WORK\2
├───a
│   └───s
└───s
    └───Docker
            Dockerfile
```

so I need to copy all files from `C:\AGENT\_WORK\2\a\s` but my docker file is in  `C:\AGENT\_WORK\2\s\Docker\Dockerfile`

I'm building the image by this command, I have given context as C:\agent_work`

```
docker build -t testapp:latest -f C:\AGENT\_WORK\2\s\Docker\Dockerfile C:\agent\_work
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1709 AS base
WORKDIR /app
ARG BINARY_SRC
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
ADD C:\AGENT\_WORK\2\a\s .
RUN ls
FROM base AS final
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApp.dll"]
```

Error:

> ADD failed: CreateFile
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder076789264\agent_work: The
>   system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: If the context directory is the `agent_work` directory at the top of your directory tree, then any `ADD` and `COPY` directives are relative to that directory; so `COPY ./a/s .`.

Comment: Nope its not working still getting the same error